# Maven Build Failure - Missing Main Class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to get started with a Spring Boot Application with Maven. I've done the tutorial from: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->

<!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My Project Folder looks like this: Test\src\main\java

Pom.xml is in Test\bin

There's only one Java file:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

If I run it with mvn spring-boot:run in cmd I'll get a build failure noting that it is unable to find a suitable main Class

Stacktrace:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.206 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-21T12:33:18+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-     maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) on project myproject:   Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property ->   [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,   please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Comment: Java file is in Test\src\main\java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Example` class is a valid Spring Boot Main class.

The problems is here :

> Pom.xml is in Test\bin

Your pom.xml is not declared at the right place.

By default Maven expects to have the `src\main\java` folder at the same level where the pom.xml is defined.

So, with this layout, Maven tries to find your classes in

```
Test\bin\src\main\java
```

But your classes are here :

> My Project Folder looks like this: Test\src\main\java

Just move the pom.xml at the root of the Test folder.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 1):

Maven expected files to be in specific places:
If your java file is in **Test\src\main\java**, then your pom file should be in **Test**, not in **Test\bin**

Just ran it with the same code and it builds fine.

You can read more about file location in maven here:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Thank you for your kind help